# paypal payment not visible checkout page in magento

Tags: php, magento, paypal, payment

I enabled `paypal payment standard` payment method in admin panel but still I can't see the option when I am in Checkout page.

see below image i enable paypal standard payment gateway

[image]

And see below image not visible paypal on frontend. what is the issue i can't find.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to resolve it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the currency you are using in your website is not supported by Paypal.

Here is the workaround to solve this problem:

- Copy core file `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php` to local directory: `app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php`
- In `Config.php` file, look for variable `$_supportedCurrencyCodes`
- It will be displayed as follows:

  ```
  protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
      'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
  ```
- Add your currency in the array. For example, I have added `NPR` currency below:

  ```
  protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
  'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB', 'NPR');
  ```

Now, paypal payment option should be displayed in your checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

you must use TLD domain, then the paypal option will appear, localhost or non TLD domain will not working

Comment: i try run paypal in localhost with fresh magento and paypal payment method shown good in checkout page

Comment: my bad, localhost is working...but domain something like domain.co.cc, already tried before and is not working :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the following
2. system / configuration page scroll down to lower left - to 'advanced' section
3. Click advanced in the advanced section
4. Scroll down to mage_paypal & Mage_PaypalUk (if UK module used) and make sure it is set to enabled
5. Saved config and test
6. If it still doesn't show then it is being overridden via the template/code

Hope that helps